# Convert Two Keys to Three Keys using AutoHotKey

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I make extensive use of the character "**Zero-width non-joiner**" in my documents and the program I use to write my documents is InDeisng.

In InDesign the shortcut for ZWNJ is **CTRL+SHIFT+2**.

Now I would like to use AutoHotKey to press **Left_CTRL+SPACE** and AutoHotKey sends **CTRL+SHIFT+2** to InDesign.

I've read this page [Remapping Keys (Keyboard, Mouse and Joystick)](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm), but sadly it works for single key mapping.

The following code doesn't work

`LCtrl & space::LCtrl & LShift & 2`

I've tried also the following code, but this doesn't work either

`LCtrl & space::
send LCtrl & LShift & 2`

Comment: See  [Keys and their symbols](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s21). To get a better understanding of how AHK works, I strongly recommend to read the whole Tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [Hotkeys Doc](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) on their website, it shows that the less than and greater than signs can be used to specify left or right of keypairs. The [Send Doc](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) details how to send key combinations including shift and control. This means that the following should be what you are looking for:

```
<^Space::
Send ^+2
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just input this character I suppose, no need to emulate the shortcut. ZWNJ is a unicode character, its code is `200c`. So try this:

```
<^space::
    send {U+200c}
return
```

Note that this will bind a system-wide shortcut, so it should work in most editors.